# Replace the values in DataFrame with pos_tags dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Here I have a Pandas Dataframe with a column 'body' which contains the texts.

```
         body
0   David Beckham's dreams of kick starting his ow...
1   Ascension Island. Picture: NASA, via Wikicommo...
2   So far this downturn, almost 10,000 direct min...
3   \nHOUSTON - Wendy Davis continued to capitaliz...
4   If something can't go on for ever, it won't. -...
5   \nPublished 04/10/2014 | 02:30\nTaoiseach Enda...
6   Ebola is having catastrophic economic conseque...
7   A British man has been raped at the Oktoberfes...
8   \nA top fashion journalist has sharply critiqu...
9   All over Ontario, giant wind turbines are spro...
10  Geneva - The Red Cross said on Monday that Sud...
11  \nPop quiz: What do pickles, vinegar, tempeh, ...

... ...
2284 rows × 1 columns
```

I want to get a DataFrame that the texts under 'body' turn into the tag form. And I do this as a basic case:

```
from nltk import pos_tag
pog = dict()
for txt in df['body'][0:3].str.split():
    text = nltk.pos_tag(txt)
    for postag in text:
        pog[postag[0]] = postag[1]
print(pog)
```

Output is:

```
{'David': 'NNP', "Beckham's": 'NNP', 'dreams': 'NNS', 'of': 'IN','kick': 'NN', 'starting': 'VBG', 'his': 'PRP$', 'own': 'JJ', 'American': 'JJ', 'soccer': 'NN', ...}
```

Then I wrote:

```
df['body'] = df['body'].replace(pog)
print(df)
```

The output is exactly like the DataFrame above, nothing changes. My thought is to use dictionary to replace the word with tags in the original DataFrame.

I am just wondering why and if anyone has a better idea to replace the words with tags, please show, thx.

Comment: `.replace` replaces whole values (in your case, strings). It cannot be used to replace substrings. For that, you should use `re.sub`.

Comment: @DyZ this is also a solution for my problem. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas, you can chain `apply` functions to get the output.

```
## sample data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'senten': ['I am not dancing','You are playing']})

df['new_sent'] = (df['senten']
                  .apply(word_tokenize)
                  .apply(pos_tag)
                  .apply(lambda x: ' '.join([y[1] for y in x])))

print(df)

             senten        new_sent
0  I am not dancing  PRP VBP RB VBG
1   You are playing     PRP VBP VBG
```